# Natural transformations and the definition of Monoidal lax functors

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

The definition of a lax monoidal functor requires the existence of a natural transformation, $\phi$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor.

1. A natural transformation relates at least 2 functors; does this mean a lax monoidal functor is actually a collection of functors? If so, how can this collection be described? For example, is there a different functor for each object in the category $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e. if $\mathcal{C}=\{A,B,C...\}$,then $F=\{F_A,F_B,F_C,...\}$)?
2. The natural transformation is defined as $\phi_{A,B}:FA\bullet FB\to F(A\otimes B)$. $\phi$'s definition contains $F$ thrice so is it relating three different kinds of $F$? I was expecting $\phi$'s definition to prominently feature two different functors, instead I see three identical ones...?
3. Why is $\phi$ defined with index $\{A,B\}$. Does this mean there is actually a family of natural transformations $\phi=\{\phi_{A,B},\phi_{A,C},\phi_{B,C},...\}$?

Thanks!

Comment: I would have avoided asking this question if wikipedia had spelt out $\phi$ was a monoidal natural transformations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_natural_transformation and not just a plain natural transformation.

Comment: Your comment does not make sense. For $\phi$ to be a monoidal natural transformation, it needs to be going between two lax monoidal functors. So you can't use monoidal natural transformations to define lax monoidal functors: that would be circular. I don't think it's even "morally true" because in order for $\phi$ to be a monoidal natural transformation, you would have to define coherence maps on the functors$(A,B) \mapsto F(A \otimes B)$ and $(A,B) \mapsto F(A) \bullet F(B)$ equipping them with the structure of lax monoidal functors, and I believe you need a braiding for this to be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope what follows will clear up your confusion.

A lax monoidal functor consists of the following data (satisfying some axioms that I won't spell out):

- *One functor* $\color{red}{F : \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}}$. This means that for all objects $A \in \mathsf{C}$ you have an object $F(A) \in \mathsf{D}$, and for all morphisms $f : A \to B$ in $\mathsf{C}$ you have a morphism $F(f) : F(A) \to F(B)$ in $\mathsf{D}$. All this needs to satisfy some axioms.
- From this functor, you can construct two different functors $\mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$, where $\mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{C}$ is the [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category) of the category $\mathsf{C}$ with itself:

  - A functor $G_1$ that maps $(A,B)$ to $F(A \otimes B)$;
  - A functor $G_2$ that maps $(A,B)$ to $F(A) \mathbin\bullet F(B)$.

  Then you want *one natural transformation* $\color{red}{\phi : G_1 \to G_2}$ between these two functors. This means that for every object $(A,B)$ of $\mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{C}$, you have the data of a morphism $\phi_{(A,B)} : F(A \otimes B) \to F(A) \mathbin\bullet F(B)$, again satisfying some axioms.

Every occurrence of $F$ represent the same functor, but you construct other functors out of it. $\phi$ is indexed by objects of $\mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{C}$, ie. pairs $(A,B)$ of objects of $\mathsf{C}$. It does relate two different functors, $G_1$ and $G_2$, which are constructed out of $F$, $\otimes$ and $\bullet$.

Comment: With all that being said, it would be (IMO) a good idea to really review the basics: what are functors, what are natural transformations, how do you compose functors... You seem to be a bit confused, and it's not a good idea to try to tackle advanced things without mastering the basics.

Comment: I don't undertand do monoidal functors relate $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ or $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. $G_1$ and $G_2$ map from $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ but $F$ maps from $\mathcal{C}$ directly.

Comment: @dumb0 A monoidal functor is actually *two* pieces of data (as I explained). The $F$, which is a functpr $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$, *and* the $\phi$, which is a natural transformation between functors $\mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$. The $F$ is the "main" data if you want, but the $\phi$ is here too and part of the data. It's like when you have a ring, you have the ring $R$, you have the addition $+ : R \times R \to R$, the zero $0 \in R$, the multiplication $* : R \times R \to R$ and the unit $1 \in R$? It's multiple pieces of data.

Comment: Wow, thanks alot. I think the wiki page should be edited to explain monoidal functors admit four components: 
1. $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$                                                 2. The associated functors $G_1, G_2: \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$             
3. The natural transformation $\phi: G_1 \rightarrow G_2$